# shell script to get time ('%T'), how to reformat output (- instead of :)

Tags: shell, unix, scripting

I use this shell script inside applescript:

```
set Date to (do shell script "date '+%Y-%m-%d'-'%T'")
return Date
```

It returns this:

```
"2012-02-15-16:01:05" #[year, month, day and time]
```

Is there some way to reformat the time to `16:01:05` to `16-01-05`. (Obviously I could do a regex on the output, but that will be messy.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A typical solution using the standard date formatting params is

```
date '+%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M-%S'
```

Not sure why you have two separate strings in your original i.e. `'+%Y-%m-%d'-'%T'`

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

You can separate the `%T` to `%H-%M-%S` then it shows the time in `00-00-00` format